# how to change extension of all the files of a directory and folder

Tags: python, ubuntu

hi i need to change the extension of all the files into CSV of a specific directory or folder and make .zip or .rar of all the CSV files. I need to run this in Ubuntu environment. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you only want to change the file extension of the files, or also need to parse the content from another format (such as xls or similar)?

Comment: just need to change the extension of files and a make zip of all csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the extension of the files you can try `os.rename` code as follows:

```
import glob
import os

#creating new folder
os.mkdir('/home/kolla/newfolder')
# for linux systems
os.system('cp /home/kolla/* /home/kolla/newfolder')

# Getting all the csv files in folder recursively
files = glob.glob('/home/kolla/newfolder/**/*', recursive=True)

for file in files:
    os.rename(file, file.split('.')[0]+'.zip') #renaming the file with .zip extension
```

NOTE: this will just change the extension and will not compress your files

Comment: this is my directory /home/kolla in ubuntu is it work for it.i need to change this in .csv extension. not only csv files i need to convert all the files into csv.

Comment: @usmankhan `files = glob.glob('/home/kolla/*', recursive=True)` if you want to read all files in the folder recursively. Please check list in `files` variable before  running `os.rename` as you might not be able to recover the file extension after running for all file extension.

Comment: and i change this `os.rename(file, file.split('.')[0]+'.csv)` because i need csv

Comment: you can change `os.rename(file, file.split('.')[0]+'.zip')` according to your requirements

Comment: is it posible in your code that i convert the file and send it to diffrent folder so i have my original file as well can u please change the code

Comment: you mean keeping original files and a new folder with `.zip` extension ?

Comment: keeping original files and the files after convert into csv will move into some diffrent folder let say /home/kolla/newfolder so i have my original files with extension and new files with csv extension as well.

Comment: man you are just great its perfectly fine i just need to add a zip code to zip new folder. thank you.